# http.serverモジュールの位置付けと役割

Tags: python

[http.serverモジュール](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server)の位置付けと役割が分からないのですが、

---

**Q1.これは何ですか？**
・シンプルなWebサーバ？　シンプルの意味は？
・開発用ローカルサーバ？　外部公開は出来ない？

---

**Q2.Nginxと比較した場合**
・Nginxに代わるもの？
・Nginxと併用するもの？

---

**Q3.起動について**
・コマンド入力が必要？
・常時起動し続けることは出来ない？

---

**Q4.PythonでWebサーバを立てる意味**
・このモジュールはPythonで書かれているのでしょうか？
・もうそうだとしたら、PythonでWebサーバを作る意味は何ですか？
・学習用途？
・Pythonで「HTTP (web) サーバを実装するためのクラスを提供する」意図は何かあると思うのですが…
・[GoでWebサーバを立てる意味も分からない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40101/go%E3%81%A7web%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E6%A7%8B%E6%88%90%E3%81%AE%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E%E8%82%A2%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)のですが、PythonでWebサーバを立てる意味も分かりません

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Q1.これは何ですか？
>   ・シンプルなWebサーバ？　シンプルの意味は？

HTTPサーバ実装において、必要最低限の機能しか提供しません。最も基本的なな`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`の場合：

- TCPポートを開いてクライアントからの接続を待機する
- 受信したHTTP要求メッセージのヘッダ部を解釈する
- HTTP応答メッセージをクライアントへ送信する

これ以上の機能は何も提供されません。いわゆるWebサーバとして成り立たせるには、少なくともサーバ上のファイル内容を読込むといった処理が必要となりますが、それはあなたの仕事になります。

さすがに...という話であれば、`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`がまさに「HTTP要求に対応したファイルを開いてHTTP応答として内容を返す」ところまで担当してくれます。

> ・開発用ローカルサーバ？　外部公開は出来ない？

用途は限定されません。技術的には外部公開も可能ですが、セキュリティ上好ましいかという別の判断基準はあります。（おすすめはしません）

---

> Q2.Nginxと比較した場合
>   ・Nginxに代わるもの？
>   ・Nginxと併用するもの？

見方によっては、`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`は **超**低機能版 Nginx ともいえます。

真面目に運用するならば、Nginxとの併用が現実的と思われます。「リバースプロキシ(Reverse Proxy)」などの単語で調べてください。

---

> Q3.起動について
>   ・コマンド入力が必要？
>   ・常時起動し続けることは出来ない？

（質問意図が不明です。単なる機能モジュール＝ソフトウエア部品にすぎません。）

---

> Q4.PythonでWebサーバを立てる意味
>   ・このモジュールはPythonで書かれているのでしょうか？
>   ・もうそうだとしたら、PythonでWebサーバを作る意味は何ですか？
>   ・学習用途？
>   ・Pythonで「HTTP (web) サーバを実装するためのクラスを提供する」意図は何かあると思うのですが…

`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`を開発中のお手軽Webサーバとして使うことはあります。
`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`はREST APIのエンドポイント実装に便利です。

> ・GoでWebサーバを立てる意味も分からないのですが、PythonでWebサーバを立てる意味も分かりません

ApacheやNginxのような「Webサーバ」ではなく、「HTTPプロトコルの受信/送信を実現するソフトウェア部品」という解釈が妥当です。

どちらかといえば`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`が本モジュールの存在意義であり、`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`は"おまけ"の実装です。

Comment: Q3は、ターミナルで毎回「$ python -m http.server」コマンド打たなければいけないのかな、と思い質問しました。「SimpleHTTPRequestHandlerは 超低機能版 Nginx ともいえます」。この説明が大変分かりやすかったです。素直にNginx使用しようと思いました

Comment: http.serverモジュールは単体起動(`-m`)にも対応していますが、こちらは「自分でコードを書かなくても`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`を簡易Webサーバとして使える」便利機能ですね。ご自身のプログラムで明示的に呼び出す分には、あなたの作ったとおりに動作するだけです。

Comment: マニュアルの1番下に書いてある起動方法は2通りあり、(-m)はその内の一つである便利機能なのですね。コメント読んでようやく意味がわかりました